# Create screenshot of Osmdroid Mapview

Tags: android, bitmap, screenshot, osmdroid

I want to create a screenshot of an Osmdroid MapView (mymapView). I am doing this:

```
Bitmap bitmap=mymapView.getDrawingCache().copy(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565, true);
```

I am getting this error:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
>   'android.graphics.Bitmap
>   android.graphics.Bitmap.copy(android.graphics.Bitmap$Config, boolean)'
>   on a null object reference

I think the reason for that is that the MapView is not ready when I try to create the bitmap. I think I would have to use the equivelant to `GoogleMap.SnapshotReadyCallback` for Osmdroid. Is there such a class for Osmdroid, or another merhod to create a screenshot of a Mapview?

Answer (score 0):

A similar functionality was introduced in Osmdroid 6.1.0. The corresponding class is [MapSnapshot](https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/blob/master/osmdroid-android/src/main/java/org/osmdroid/views/drawing/MapSnapshot.java).

A sample usage of this can be found here: [SampleMapSnapshot](https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/blob/master/OpenStreetMapViewer/src/main/java/org/osmdroid/samplefragments/data/SampleMapSnapshot.java)

A simple usage would look like this, here pMapView is the Mapview we want to snapshot.

```java
final MapSnapshot mapSnapshot = new MapSnapshot(new MapSnapshot.MapSnapshotable() {
            @Override
            public void callback(final MapSnapshot pMapSnapshot) {
                if (pMapSnapshot.getStatus() != MapSnapshot.Status.CANVAS_OK) {
                    return;
                }
                final Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(pMapSnapshot.getBitmap());
                // Do something with the bitmap like save to file
            }
        }, MapSnapshot.INCLUDE_FLAG_UPTODATE, pMapView);
new Thread(mapSnapshot).start();
```

Note: For some reason if you call this directly during onCreate, it causes a crash. Otherwise it works as expected

Reference : https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/issues/1737